# Integral over product of 1/x, exp(-x), J0 and J1 Bessel function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

Is there an analytic expression for the integral

$$\int_0^\infty dx \frac{1}{x} e^{-\lambda x} J_1(xy) J_0(xz)$$

with $\lambda\geq0$ and $y,z>0$?

I know that there is a (complicated) closed form for the integral without the $\frac{1}{x}$, but that expression can't be integrated with respect to $\lambda$, so expressing $\frac{1}{x}$ as an integral of $e^{-\lambda x}$ over $\lambda$ is not an option.

Numerical integration is slow and unreliable due to the oscillatory behavior of the integrand.

Edit: Possibly, the original integral is to general. In the end, I am trying to solve it for a specific value of $\lambda$, namely

$$\int_0^\infty dx \frac{1}{x} (1-e^{-x}) J_1(xy) J_0(xz)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is in Gradshteyn-Ryzhik formula 6.626.1. Note that there is a mistake in the book. The correct result is (valid for $z\geq y$)

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x} e^{-\lambda x} J_1(x y) J_0(x z) = \frac{y}{2\lambda} \sum_{m=0}^\infty C_m \;{}_2 F_1(m+\tfrac12,m+1;1;-z^2/\lambda^2) \left( - \frac{y^2}{4 \lambda^2}\right)^m \tag{1}$$
with $C_m$ the Catalan numbers. The series is alternating an decaying quickly; it is thus well-suited for numerical calculation.

In particular, the op is interested in the result for $\lambda=0$. We can take the limit of (1) and obtain (also valid for $z \geq y$)
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x}  J_1(x y) J_0(x z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty
 2 (m+1) (C_m)^2\,\left(\frac{y}{4z}\right)^{2m+1}.$$

For $z\leq y$, we need the alternative expansion
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x} e^{-\lambda x} J_1(x y) J_0(x z) = \frac{y}{2\lambda} \sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+1)C_m \;{}_2 F_1(m+\tfrac12,m+1;2;-y^2/\lambda^2) \left( - \frac{z^2}{4 \lambda^2}\right)^m ;\tag{2}$$
and evaluating it for $\lambda=0$, we obtain the result (valid for $z\leq y$)
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x}  J_1(x y) J_0(x z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1-2m}
 (m+1)^2 (C_m)^2\,\left(\frac{z}{4y}\right)^{2m}.$$

Comment: Under the condition $\lambda>1$ (since $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$). Also, it's about as difficult to evaluate numerically as the original form (would you consider it analytic?).

Comment: @user3582129: the final sum is alternating (note that ${}_2F_1$ is always a positive number). Summing an alternating series is much easier to evaluate numerically than an oscillating integral.

Comment: I see, if the sum is alternating and the absolute values are monotonically decreasing then I see why it's easier to evaluate. If the integral diverges for $\lambda=0$, then my second integral in the original question would diverge, too?

Comment: @user3582129: it turns out that the result in Gradshteyn is incorrect. I rederived the results. It makes sense to distinguish two cases ($y<z$ and $y>z$). Also for $\lambda=0$ one should take the limit by hand. I have given the results in my answer. I hope this helps (the expressions converge rather quickly).

Comment: Tested for various $y$ and $z$, seems to give the correct result. Conversion is good for $y$ sufficiently different from $z$. Is there a performance tweak for $y=z+\epsilon$ with $|\epsilon|$ small? Also, you should consider writing to the editors of the book.

Comment: Also, the sign of the term in the sum in (1) does not change with every $m$, but after $y-z$. The terms in the sum for $\lambda=0$ do not change their sign at all. Hence, I don't see an easy way to estimate the error when evaluating only up to a finite $m_\text{max}$